# data frame to structured list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr

This is an interesting question that I can't seem to find the answer to. Let me just jump right in. I need to take a data frame created from:

```
TPA <- ddply(MT,~plot,summarise,TPA=length(unique(tree.number))*50)
> TPA

plot  TPA
1   10A  700
2   10B 1000
3    1A  900
4    1B  950
5    2A  950
6    2B  650
7    3A  650
8    3B 1350
9    4A 1450
10   4B 1350
11   5A  850
12   5B 1100
13   6A 1050
14   6B  550
15   7A  850
16   7B  800
17   8A 2450
18   8B  950
19   9A 1150
20   9B 1000
```

and convert this to:

```
y <- list(one=c(900,950), two=c(950,650), three=c(650,1350), four=c(1450,1350),     five=c(850,1100), six=c(1050,550), seven=c(850,800), eight=c(2450,950), nine=c(1150,1000), ten=c(700,1000))
> y
$one
[1] 900 950

$two
[1] 950 650

$three
[1]  650 1350

$four
[1] 1450 1350

$five
[1]  850 1100

$six
[1] 1050  550

$seven
[1] 850 800

$eight
[1] 2450  950

$nine
[1] 1150 1000

$ten
[1]  700 1000
```

Notice that 1A in the data frame corresponds to "one" in the list. I know how to go the other way from a list to a data frame, but I can't figure out how to go from a data frame to a list. I have a function that requires a list to feed into the function. For completeness, here is the part that uses the list:

```
yi.bar <- unlist(lapply(y,mean))
s2i <- unlist(lapply(y,var))
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the numbers from `plot`:

```
TPA$plot_num = as.numeric(regmatches(TPA$plot, regexpr("\\d+", TPA$plot, perl=TRUE)))
```

Then it's a really simple `dlply` call:

```
TPA_split = dlply(TPA, .(plot_num), function(df) df$TPA)
```

Output:

```
> TPA_split
$`1`
[1] 900 950

$`2`
[1] 950 650

$`3`
[1]  650 1350

$`4`
[1] 1450 1350

$`5`
[1]  850 1100

$`6`
[1] 1050  550

$`7`
[1] 850 800

$`8`
[1] 2450  950

$`9`
[1] 1150 1000

$`10`
[1]  700 1000
```

Comment: You might want to wrap an `as.numeric` in there somewhere so that the auto-ordering doesn't put 10 ahead of 2.

Comment: @thelatemail: Cheers, fixed.

Comment: I ended up using this method as it fit into my workflow a little bit better. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty straightforward `split` operation - no need for add-on packages:

```
split(dat$TPA,as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",dat$plot)))

#$`1`
#[1] 900 950
# 
#$`2`
#[1] 950 650
#
#$`3`
#[1]  650 1350
#...
```

And if anyone was considering tackling the task of converting numbers to text representations, you've been beaten to the punch:

http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Papers/numbers2words.pdf

Comment: Thanks to both of you! These worked great! Now...if only R could order Pizza.

Comment: @user2325155 You are about 9 years late: `fortune(66)` (from the `fortunes` package).